# How to simply call a method from container1 to container2 in .net core using api like https://localhost:5001/api/Movies/getname

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose, containers

I can create and run 2 containers which are in separate project. both run and work with no issue.

But I want to call a method from one container1 which returns a string like "hey its me from container1" by container2.

I am new to this kind of development. any help would be appreciated.

Notes:

- I don't use compose file yet. actually I tried but didn't understand how to create network and connect containers them, to each other.many tutorials were checked out but didn't get how to do it.
- both containers are in same network
- I dont use any SQL or any other complicated code just want a method to call a api like " https://localhost:5001/api/Movies/getname." and returning the string.
- the projects are created in .net core(VS 2017).
- A problem I am facing is when I add composer file to prj can not debug the project it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a docker network for this. I have achieved this using docker-compose. In the following example I have defined a network back-tier and both the services belong to it. After this your application can access your DB with its service name http://database:27017.

```
 version: '3'

    networks:
      back-tier:

    services:
      database:
        build: ./Database
        networks:
          - back-tier
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
      backend:
        build: ./Backend
        networks:
          - back-tier
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
        depends_on:
          - database
```

Comment: thx @bilal-ali-jafri does it work for two separate project of separate solutions ?
each project is micro-service (container)

as I understood both containers are in same solution

Comment: If you want your containers to communicate through different machines then best approach is initializing a swarm, in this way both the machine's containers will be able to communicate to each other by service name.

Comment: no, same machine but two separate solution. @bilal-ali-jafri

Comment: What do you mean by separate solution?

Comment: As long as the services are on the same machine. The services can access the network if specified under its service.

Comment: I have two project. each has it's own docker-compose file. how to create docker-compose file for each. it seems you have only one docker-compose file but I have two solution/project-> containers in same network.

Comment: in which project should i create "networks: back-tier " the first one or second ? I want to call a method of container1 from container2

Comment: Yeah It will work for that too. In this case it will find the network with specified name. If its already created it will join it otherwise it will create one for you.

Comment: You can define it on both. It will join the network if exist. Otherwise it will create one

Answer (score 0):

you need to use docker-compose to create network.thats it.

Comment: I know but will you please elaborate more on this. I am very new to this things